# Prevent background image from scaling

Tags: css, background-image, scale

I am creating a slider with custom "prev/next" navigation-arrows.
All the animations works fine. I use the `transform: scale()` to scale up the arrows when hovering and it all works fine. I just have one problem..

**I want to prevent the arrow images to scale too.**

I think I have tried everything: I've used somekind of :before/:after *(see below)* and it worked pretty good. But not in Safari *(No transition when hover)*.

http://jsfiddle.net/XF4Qj/5/

---

Then I tried something else: Putting a span inside the arrow container, and when the arrow container was scaled up, the span was scaled down, but it didn't looked good at all *(See below)*.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajngc/1/

---

I have tried for hours, but I cannot get it to work in all major browsers.

So the question is: **How to I prevent the arrow-images from scaling too, and just preserve their original dimensions?**

It's only the white circle that schould be scaled up, and **not** the background image.

I've created a third fiddle, which has all the working code from my slider-arrow-functions:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajngc/2/

Could be really great if someone could help me with this.

Thank you very much
- Jesper

Comment: Your first fiddle works in safari for me

Comment: A part of it works yes. But the transition doesn't. I donno why

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `transform()`ing those elements, why not just change the size? See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XF4Qj/10/).

```
.arrow:hover {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
}

.prev:hover {
    left: 35px;
}

.next:hover {
    right: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Be corse this method is very shaky/jumpy in Safari